# R package "rhandsontable" does not display the "NA" character sequence

Tags: r, shiny, rhandsontable

The Bloomberg exchange code for Dutch equities is "NA", for example "RDA NA Equity". I need to display the exchange code on a separate column in a handsontable. The default rendering function interprets the 2 character string "NA" as an Not Applicable value and shows a blank cell instead. I dealt with this by appending a space to all exchange codes. This is very unsatisfying. Is there some kind of setting that can prevent the handsontable renderer from "squelching" "NA" strings ?

Answer (score 1):

You can apply a custom text renderer (by default `rhandsontable` changes `NA` to empty string)

```
library(rhandsontable)
data = data.frame(a=rep(NA, 5))
rhandsontable(data) %>% hot_cols(renderer="
    function (instance, td, row, col, prop, value, cellProperties) {
      Handsontable.renderers.TextRenderer.apply(this, arguments);
    }
")
```